# Have a page for a non-profit, can't find proper fbid for open graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph, html

I know similar questions have been asked, but none of the solutions worked for me. I just started a page for a non-profit and I am implementing the open graph on our main site. When I scrape the site with http: //developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, I get

> Object at URL 'http: //www.desertmuseumdigitallibrary.org/public1/detail.php?id=ASDM23540' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '114003368752609' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

I believe that this is probably the page id, but it does work on https://graph.facebook.com/114003368752609. I have been unable to locate any other number that will work on https: //graph.facebook.com/. The page that I am referred to on login is http://www.facebook.com/pages/ASDM-Sonoran-Desert-Digital-Library/114003368752609 and the name "ASDM-Sonoran-Desert-Digital-Library" doesn't work for https: //graph.facebook.com/ either.

I have also tried creating an app, hoping that this would give me an app_id I could use, but the link sends me straight to my regular page.

Answer (score 0):

114003368752609 is a page ID according to the graph API result above

That field is supposed to be the user ID of users who will administer the URL for insights purposes; it's not possible to use a Page ID for this

If you're splitting this access among several users, you need to use an App ID (created at https://developers.facebook.com/apps )- in which case the admins configured for that app will have access to the insights.

What you need is either:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="CSV LIST OF USER IDS OF FACEBOOK USERS" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP ID OF AN APP" />
```

Comment: Thank you Igy, but when I try to go to the link you included, it takes me straight to my regular facebook page. Do you have any idea how to get around that?

Comment: If you can't access the apps dashboard are you sure this isn't a roundabout duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account ?

Comment: You are right, Igy, that is the same problem. Thanks for the solution re apps. So, how can I find my actual user ID to insert in my main website's meta tags?

Comment: If it's a business account, I'm not 100% sure how to get the user ID unfortunately - it's easy enough to get via the API (e.g. use the [Graph API Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me) to access `/me` and the user ID will be in the response) but i'm not sure about doing it from facebook's main interface

Comment: That means you're not using a valid access token - did you authorise the graph api explorer to access your data?